# Create a Social Network App in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook

I already have created a web-based social network using PHP and MYSQL. I wanted to advance our marketing more by create a mobile app version of it. I tried WebView on Android Studio and it somewhat works.

Downside of using it though is that it still loads a little slower compared to an actual Social Networking App like Facebook, Instagram, etc. since its design, settings, and codes are preloaded on the app itself and not fetching everything from the web like the WebView.

I tried searching online and they only gave me this pre-made websites where they offer to create a "pre-made" social networking app. I want to hard-code and design everything for maximum creativity. So here's my question:

**SERVER-DATABASE**
I currently use MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN. In developing an Android-like environment where you need to store some info online or server-based, what is the alternative way in doing so? Like is there a MYSQL in Android?

**LANGUAGE**

I know it's primary language in Android Studio is JAVA. In making a social networking app, are there any third-party languages that I have to learn like PHP in web?

**GUIDES**

 I'm really bummed out that I spent hours searching the web for some tutorials/guides in making a social networking app and they all said WebView. I know it's possible since Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc. are social networking apps and I'm sure it's not WebView (lol). Is there any guides/websites/tutorials out there that could help me?

Thanks fellow devs!

## UPDATE

I know this is probably a noob's question for all ya'll professional devs out there but you shouldn't really like down vote it. We all have to start somewhere, no one's born to be a professional coder all of a sudden. Newbie's like me needs help from you guys, we're supposed to be a family around here. I'm really disappointed, I'm sorry.

Comment: You should prepare API on your server-side which will be used by Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course a WebView is slower compared to Facebook and the other social media apps. The main reason for this is, that with an app you don't have to load everything, like style elements and such things, each time again. With an app you download all this stuff with the installation and don't ever have to download them again. This has the advantage, that you just have to load plain data each time your app connects to the webserver. I prefer to use JSON for data exchange, but you have to write some API in PHP.

So the steps for you are:

1. Create a concept, which data your app will exchange with the server
2. Based on this concept write a PHP-API that collects the data from your MySQL Database and returns the queried data in JSON (don' forget to think about security concepts at this point)
3. In Android you have to create a Model for your data. For Example: If you want to get a Profile, you have to create a Profile-Classe with all the attributes and Getter- and Setter-Methods.
4. Create a DataAccessObject (DAO) which must run in an asynchronous task, because there you load the data from your API over the URL
5. Your DAO creates an object of your Model and populates the objects attributes with the JSON-Data
6. Your app can do whatever it wants with the object.

Don't be to specific when searching for tutorials and help in web. You won't find a tutorial about programming a second Facebook, but you will find a lot of Tutorials about data exchange between Android Apps and Webserver/MySQL.

Here are some links, that might be interesting for you:

- http://androidexample.com/AsyncroTask_Example_To_Get_Server_Data_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=59
- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Good luck with your project. I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really a good help for me!